# docker-composeで待ち受けメッセージの改行を抑止するための設定方法

Tags: docker, docker-compose, teraterm

`docker-compose restart`の古いバージョンでは、時間のかかるコマンドの実行が完了するまで、
実行中メッセージが紙芝居のように表示されていました。
（これってどのような仕組みで実現しているのでしょうか。）

古い版のdokcer-compose(versionはメモし忘れ)では、実行中メッセージは改行されずに、上書きされます。
一方、最新版のdokcer-compose(v2.23.3)では、実行中メッセージが改行されて表示されてしまいました。

古い版のときと同様に、実行中メッセージを改行せずに表示させることは可能でしょうか？

◇古い版のdocker-composeの実行結果（期待している結果）
Restartingというメッセージが、改行されずに表示されます。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

◇最新版の実行結果（NGな結果）
Restartingというメッセージが、改行されて表示されます。
コマンドプロンプトと同様に、改行されないようにしたいです。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dokcer-compose(v2.23.3)では、実行中メッセージが改行されて表示されてしまいました。
```

新しいバージョンv2.4.1に更新したところ、再現しなくなりました。
余計な改行はされず、適切な表示となりました。

```
# docker-composeのインストール
sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/v2.4.1/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
docker-compose --version
# 再起動 or ログインしなおす sudo reboot
```

ちなみに、紙芝居のように改行せずにメッセージを更新する方法は、
「ANSIエスケープ」という技術を利用しているそうです。